# Does this character ever hint he is the father of Robert Arryn of the Vale?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

There's a fan theory that [Petyr Baelish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petyr_Baelish) is the secret father of Robert Arryn, the son of Lysa Tully and presumably Jon Arryn.

He warmly greets Robyn each time he sees him, and this is something he does not do for others. He's not affectionate with anyone else, but he hugs this young boy.

He once impregnated Lysa Tully, but forced her to drink an abortifacient poison to cause a miscarriage. (Which also removes Jon Arryn's doubts about whether his wife was fertile enough to get pregnant.)

Jon Arryn was nearly 70 when he died, and Lysa said he was too old to get her pregnant.

Baelish chose the mockingbird as his sigil, and the [mockingbird](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mockingbird) is known for getting other birds to raise their eggs.

Robin's hair color matches that of Petyr Baelish, but does not match that of Jon Arryn. Jon Arryn was blonde as a young man.

**So did Baelish ever hint or say that sweet young Robin was his secret son?**

Comment: Did you get that idea from [here](http://asoiaf.westeros.org/index.php?/topic/142496-is-petyr-baelish-robert-arryns-real-father/)?

Comment: @Mooz No, I heard that fan-theory on YouTube.

Comment: Could you link or reference that fan theory please.

Comment: On the other hand - in the books there seems to be a widespread assumption that Robert will die young and without issue. Baelish doesn't seem phased by this, instead manoeuvring Sansa into position to make a claim on Winterfell once Harry the Heir inherits the Vale and its armies.

Comment: Where I learned of the Secret Son Fan Theory. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6vxB_BqFJN0

Comment: "He warmly greets Robyn each time he sees him"

Or maybe he's really good at kissing ass?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> He once impregnated Lysa Tully, but forced her to drink an abortifacient poison to cause a miscarriage. (Which also removes Jon Arryn's doubts about whether his wife was fertile enough to get pregnant.)

In the book he's not the one who forced her to do that. It was her father.

As to whether Robin is his son--I doubt that. It's possible, but unlikely, namely because the chance of discovery if they had an affair was too high. And, it's better for him if the heir is legit.

By the time Sweet Robin was spawned, Baelish was much more cautious, and while he might hold out the idea of love to Lysa, it was possible that he didn't actually have sex with her. A legitimate heir is better for him.

But no. **Baelish never did hint or say that Robin was his secret son (and neither did Lysa for that matter, and she was nuts enough to spill any large truth before she went bye-bye out the door).** That is not to say the possibility does not exist, just that it hasn't been laid out this way. Lysa's fervent belief that "the seed is strong" referred to Jon's son tracks with that.

Comment: You are correct it was her father who aborted the kid. Lysa didn't even know what he gave her to drink (As per her own account). Catelyn figured it out when her father kept begging for forgiveness and saying "Tansy". +1